# Relative interior inclusion of convex sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Is $\text{ri}(C-D) = \text{ri}(C) - \text{ri}(D)$, where $C$ and $D$ are nonempty convex sets?

If so please give the proof
If that's not the case could you give a counterexample and what is the inclusion there?

Comment: What do you mean by $C-D$? The set of elements that can be expressed as c-d with $c\in C$ and $d\in D$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this equality does not have to hold, although it sometimes does.  Also, the left-hand side does not have to include the right-hand side, or vice versa.  Here are some examples:

${\rm relint\ } (C\setminus D)=({\rm relint\ }C)\setminus({\rm relint\ } D)$: Any disjoint $C$ and $D$ will do for this.  Both sides are then equal to ${\rm relint\ }C$.

${\rm relint\ } (C\setminus D)\subsetneq({\rm relint\ }C)\setminus({\rm relint\ } D)$: Take $C$ to be a circle together with its interior, and $D$ to be a closed segment $PQ$ in the interior of $C$.  Then ${\rm relint\ }D$ is the open segment $PQ$, so the right-hand side is the interior of $C$ with the open segment $PQ$ removed, while the left-hand side is the interior of $C$ with the closed segment $PQ$ removed.

${\rm relint\ } (C\setminus D)\supsetneq({\rm relint\ }C)\setminus({\rm relint\ } D)$: For this case, we need to make the affine hull of $C\setminus D$ differ from that of $C$.  Let $P$, $Q$, and $R$ be three noncollinear points, let $C$ be the triangle $PQR$ (vertices, edges, and interior all included), and let $D$ be $C$ with the closed segment $PQ$ omitted.  Then both $C$ and $D$ have the same relative interior, so the right-hand side is empty.  However $C\setminus D$ is the closed segment $PQ$, so it has relative interior the open segment $PQ$.

Neither side contains the other: We again play with the affine hulls.  Let $Q$ be a cube (vertices, edges, faces, and interior all included) and let its bottom face be $EFGH$.  Let $D$ be the cube $Q$ with the closed segment $EF$ omitted and let $C$ be the square $EFGH$ (vertices, edges, and interior.)  Then ${\rm relint\ }D$ is only the interior of $Q$ so the right-hand side is ${\rm relint\ }C$, which is the interior of the square $EFGH$.  On the other hand $C\setminus D$ is only the closed segment $EF$ so its relative interior is the open segment $EF$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $C\backslash D=\left\{x: x\in C \text{ and } x \not\in D\right\}$ and $C-D$ denote the same set? In convex analysis, it is very common to write $C-D=\left\{ x:  x=c-d \text{ with } c \in C \text{ and } d\in D\right\}$.

Comment: I was assuming that $-$ meant $\setminus$, but I think now that you are right, $-$ probably means pointwise $-$ here.

Answer (score 2):

I think Sergio Parreiras is right. We assume $C - D = \{x: x=c-d \text{ with } c\in C \text{ and } d\in D\}$

Here is my intuitive explanation.

1. We first show the forward inclusion must be true, i.e., $ri(C_1 - C_2) \subset ri(C_1) - ri(C_2)$.

Suppose $x\in ri(C_1 - C_2)$, then $\exists, y\in C_1, z\in C_2$ such that $x = y-z$. There are three cases:

a) If $y \in ri(C_1)$ and $z\in ri(C_2)$, then the forward inclusion is true.

b) If $y \in ri(C_1)$ and $z\notin ri(C_2)$, then we can tweak $y$ and $z$ to be $y'$ and $z'$ such that $y' \in ri(C_1)$ and $z' \in ri(C_2)$ and $x = y'-z'$.

c) If $y \notin ri(C_1)$ and $z\notin ri(C_2)$, then $x=y-z \notin ri(C_1 - C_2)$

2. We now show the backward inclusion must be true. It is true because of part a) in the forward inclusion.

These are intuitive explanation. You need to translate them in mathematical language, but it should be easy to write out the details.